# How do I add a geometry node into a frame without changing the frame?

Tags: node-editor, interface, geometry-nodes

When I drag a geometry node into a frame, it removes the frame from all the other geometry nodes. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Just try to move more nodes into the same frame and see what happens...

Comment: sounds weird. Can you show us a video of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A frame always adapts to the size of the contained nodes.

If you drag and drop a node into a frame, it will resize accordingly.

However, if you just create a frame and resize it, it will not contain any nodes yet and will adjust to the first node you put into it.

Just try to move more nodes into the same frame and see what happens...

[image]